# How to save JSONdata from API-call(GET) to later use for an API-request(PUT)?

Tags: swift

This is what i am trying to accomplish:

1. Use a barcode scanner to scan an item and send a "**GET REQUEST**" to retrieve json data.
2. Modify the data with user input (change number, text etc).
3. Use the modified data/variable to send out a "**PUT REQUEST**" as httpbody.

I dont know what the best way to accomplish this is, im so lost! Can i somehow return the variable **"parameters"** out of the function so that i can modify it and send it out with another function?

**The below code is not the full code, i removed a big part to make it easier to read. It contains a "get" function, dont know where to go from here.**

Thanks for checking it out, just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import QRCodeReader
import Alamofire

// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let objects: [Object]
}


// MARK: - Object
struct Object: Codable {
    let inventory: [Inventory]
}


// MARK: - Inventory
struct Inventory: Codable {
    let coordinates: String

}





    func test() {
        
        // MARK: - LOGIN DETAILS
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(username: "username", password: "password"),
            .accept("application/json")]
        
        // MARK: - API REQUEST
        AF.request("URL LINK", headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
            
            // MARK: - CHECK FOR ERRORS
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
                
                // MARK: - ERROR MESSAGE
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                { let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: "Something went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    
                self.present(alert, animated: true)}
                return}
            
            // MARK: - PRINT RESPONSE
            if response.response != nil
            {print (response.response!) }
            
            // MARK: - PRINT DATA
            if response.data != nil
            { print(response.data!)
              let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               do
            {
                let api = try decoder.decode(Main.self, from: response.data!)
                
                let parameters = [
                        "meta": [
                            "language": "en"
                        ],
                        "request": [
                             "inventory": [
                            [
                                "id": 6534206,
                                "warehouseid": 1,
                                "instock": 3,
                                "threshold": 0,
                                "reserved": 0,
                                "coordinates": "\(api.objects[0].inventory[0].coordinates)",
                                "note": "",
                                "prodno": 25669,
                                "soldout": 0
                            ]
                        ]
                        ]
                ]
                
            }
               
               catch {
                   print("Error in JSON parsing")
               }
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the closure to return the value out of the function. This practice is functional programming, almost using for async function.

```
func test(completion: ([String: AnyObject]) -> ()) {
    ...
    let param = [“meta”: [“language”: “en”],...]
    completion(param)
}
```

And then, to use it:

```
test(completion: { param in
    // handle the “param”
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to help me. I've tried the above code but get the following error when entering "completion(param) ----  Cannot convert value of type '[String : [String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]', how would i go about solving this?

Comment: Let's try func test(completion: ([String: Any]) -> ()) { ... }. You can change [String: Any] to the type of response value that you want to get outside that function @Axxi

Comment: Hey! It worked, but this is not exactly what i was looking for. I want one button to "get" data  and another button to "put" data (but modified). A completionhandler makes this work if i only use 1 button, but i need 2 buttons, how would i go about it?

Comment: You need to keep the param as an local variable of a class. For example: you have a ViewControllerA, it contains 2 buttons. First button will call test() and then get the param, asign it to the existing local variable that you have just defined already. Then, button 2 will use that local variable

Comment: Define something like this in your class:  private var paramData: [String: Any]? = nil. In completion of test() just asign the param to it: paramData = param

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked. I really appreciste the time you took to help me <3